# GroupBy two long type

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

```
List<obj> lst;

lst = result.GroupBy(x => x.id && x.secondID).Select(x=> new obj
{
    id = x.First().id.GetValueOrDefault(),
}).ToList();
```

Originally the above code was groupby only `x.id` but I wanted to expand the groupby by having `secondID` as well.

The problem I'm getting is `Operator && cannot be applied to of type opperands long? and long?`.

May I know what have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = result.GroupBy(x => new { x.id, x.secondID }).Select(x=> new obj
{
    id = x.Key.id.GetValueOrDefault(),
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. May I know if there is any difference by using `Key` instead of `First()`?

Comment: `Key` - is your grouping entity `new { x.id, x.secondID }`, First() - is just first element of group

Answer (score 0):

Use this one for multiple fields grouping on list

```
group x by new { x.Column1, x.Column2 }

.GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2 })
```